# What would be the best underwater environment to set up their civilization?

Tags: civilization, ocean

So, on the planet Oceanus, their exist a species, called the Crustaceanoids, who live in an aquatic environment. They are crustaceans, no duh, and are crab like animals. They are exceptionally intelligent, and already have Stone Age level tools. They also have a writing system, which relies on dead Crustaceanoid shells to make markings on. They also have agriculture, growing algae and herding domesticated fish for food. They will be in the plot of my story, but a need a suitable place for these creatures to live. It has to fit the criteria below.

- It has to be shielded from waves, as the backwash can carry out Crustaceanoids and destroy crops.
- It has to be protected form predators, who often feast on the Crustaceanoids. It must have lots of places or safe hiding spots (the Crustaceanoids are about 6 inches big)
- It has to have plenty of flat areas for herding fish, and rocky surfaces for growing food.

So, which aquatic environment could these Crustaceanoids inhabit?

Comment: What kind of research have you done on the topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reefs.

Lots of hiding places, protected from waves, lots of food. It's prime habitat.

Your creatures could shape the coral to their needs or even induce the coral to build to their requirements just as we can shape the way plants grow into hedges.

Comment: Can you expand more. I’m not 100% on the rules, but I’m pretty sure one sentence answers are allowed. No offense

Comment: @DTCooper ok, done.

Answer (score 3):

This civilisation is fairly advanced - a crustacean stone age level with the ability to farm and write.

There are of course no examples on Earth of such creatures, the only civilisation that has retained these abilities is of course humans.

The beginning of our civilisation started sporadically, but many argue initially upon the creation of farming (in your case, algae farms). In our timeline this occurred 105,000 years ago. This has enabled enough stability and centralisation to create towns and cities.

In contrast, domestication of animals only came 10,500 years ago - much later, and stone age tools too.

Clearly then in order for your civilisation to reach where it is now it needs to be your algae farms that determine its origins. For this we need standing pools or slow flowing rivers that are fairly warm and shallow and plenty of nutrients. We are therefore looking not at ocean depths or even sandy shorelines, and likely in isolated low-lying close to shore silt land areas with an abundance of nitrates and plant life (almost swamp-like areas).

Such areas are also stable enough to enable the establishment of towns, from which further development of your civilisation may occur.